# Good solution for a "Tagged container"?

Tags: types, software-design, bitmask

In my problem, I have a set of different types and a `Holder` (or Container if you prefer that term) class for these types. Each `Holder` can be associated to elements of any type but with arbitrary restrictions.

The problem is that the structure of the types can be quite complex, I can have subtypes like `A1,A2,A3,B1,B2` with some different behaviours.

For example, I could have a class `Car` and a subtype `Convertible`, and another class `Helicopter` with an `Apache` subtype, and make a container be able to associate with only this two specific types. Both `Car` and `Helicopter` would be derived from the same parent class (`Vehicle`, following the example).

This is not really a hard problem *per se*, but I want to make it flexible and maintainable enough. The types will not be hardcoded, but come from configuration files that should be easy to generate and read; configuring the `Holders` should be as easy as `A1 | B3 | C2`. So I'm not finding the sweet spot between flexibility and usability.

There must be some solution or even a pattern. Thought something with bit masks but I don't have experience with them and I don't know the best way to use them.

Do you know some good solutions to this specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Manager that stores the different types and gives its corresponding ID as an unsigned int. My software doesn't really care about what arbitrary tags the user defines, so a single number for each tag combination is just fine. We can think of a type as an abstraction of the list of types each element has.

My manager assigns an ID to each tag combination so if you put the same tag two times it gives the same result. Then, integers are easier to compare than lists of any type.

It's also waaay simpler to use and implement than the other options I was thinking about.

Here you have a C# prototype I did, it's probably not definitive but you get the idea:

```
public class TypeManager{
    private static uint _ID = 0;
    private static Dictionary<string,uint> typemap = new Dictionary<string,uint>();

    public static uint GetType<T>(List<T> types) {
        string key = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < types.Count; ++i)
            key += types[i] + ">";
        return GetType(key);
    }

    public static uint GetType(string key) {
        if(!typemap.ContainsKey(key)) {
            typemap[key] = _ID++;
        }
        return typemap[key];
    }
}
```